# Uploadify error with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

Hi I am trying to use JQuery Uploadify plugin using the following code:

```
$('input#uploadFile_CSV').uploadify({
                'uploader'  : '/images/uploadify.swf',
                'cancelImg' : '/images/cancel.png',
                'script'    : 'RequestController',
                'buttonText': 'Import CSV',
                'scriptData': {'command': 'ImportCSVFileCommand', 
                                'workspaceId': $.workspaceGlobalInformation.id},
                'method'    : 'GET',
                'auto': true,
                'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                    resetCSVDialogOptions();
                    showCSVImportOptions(response);
                }
            });
```

I keep getting a HTTP error and I can't read my script data at the server end. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link to your site?

Comment: Sorry, but its not on a public server. Yet. I would be more than happy to provide more information as required.

Comment: I debugged with the error object that it returns me. It gives a 500 error.

Comment: When is the error occurring? When selecting files or during the actual upload?

Comment: I am able to select the files. I think it happens during the actual upload. My server does not see any script data that I pass it through.

Comment: Is it only and IE problem? Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: From what I have read the HTTP 500 error comes from an incorrect script reference, and seeing as how you aren't getting any script data on the server, my guess is it's something to do with that.

Comment: Yes, it works on all other browsers fine.

Comment: http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/7313/the-reason-for-my-http-500-error/p1 Maybe this?